# creating a pandas dataframe by using several matlab files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matlab, data-preprocessing

How can I read,load and convert ** several** .mat files into a python pandas dataframe at once?

try to make a pandas dataframe with .mat files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```html
import glob
import scipy.io
import pandas as pd

# Get a list of all .mat files in the current directory
mat_files = glob.glob("*.mat")

# Initialize an empty list to store the data
data = []

# Loop through each .mat file
for file in mat_files:
    # Load the .mat file using scipy.io.loadmat
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat(file)
    
    # Extract the data from the .mat file
    data.append(mat['data'])

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```